# iPad mobile safari printing

Tags: ios, ipad, printing, safari

I need to print web pages from Safari to a mobile printer in the field using an iPad.  I can't seem to figure this out - any ideas, suggestions?

As I understand it, I cannot connect to a printer via bluetooth - iOS does not allow this.

I won't be in an area with WiFi - so I can't connect that way.

I have two thoughts....

1. Can I use the mobile hotspot on the iPad to create the WiFi network and then print to the Wifi printer using this network? Would that work?
2. Using the camera connection kit/USB attachment to print to a USB connected printer.  Would that work?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be so appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: First one is something you can try and then use something mentioned here http://ipadacademy.com/2012/03/how-to-print-from-your-ipad-summary-of-printer-and-printing-options I dont have any experience with these though.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your printer, you can sometimes print photos from the **printer** end. If your printer is able to see photos on your iPad using the camera connection kit, then you could take a screenshot of the webpage, then find the image using the photo browser function of your printer, and print the image.

If your printer is airprint enabled, then it might be possible to do as you suggest and connect the printer to the iPad hotspot, but I don't have an iPad that can create WiFi hotspots, so I can't test it.

Comment: Thank you @daviewales - I'll have to give it a test on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Use the app Print n Share ; I print recipes and articles daily from Safari through this app. It only takes seconds and has plenty of other nice features so seems to be very useful and powerful - In fact its my only non Apple app on my iPad home screen!

The app will use the personal hotspot on the device for an adhoc wifi so I even use it on the road with my portable HP H470 printer in the trunk (yes I tried Bluetooth too).

Answer (score 0):

Just found this link that seems to confirm that a mobile hotspot can indeed be used as a WIFI network for printing via an AirPrint printer.  Excellent.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4007254?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Some printers can have cameras connect over USB directly (as in, 30-pin/Lighning end plugged into the iPad, USB end plugged into the printer).

For example, photo printing kiosks (such as the ones at Target) let you do this. I have printed photos from my iPhone plenty of times that way.

Assuming you're buying a new printer and don't *need* wireless, this should work the most reliably, I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to set up a mobile printer to work with iPad, but it requires you have an iPad with the mobile hotspot feature. I've created a parts list and a youtube video to help you get it set up. They can be found here:

http://makethisstuffwork.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-set-up-mobile-printer-to-work.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! If you just provide a link as an answer, it’s useful to provide some context or quote the relevant part of the linked page, so that the answer remains useful even if the link goes offline.